# How does an Ability Capsule interact with Hidden Abilities?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

In Pokemon Ultra Moon, I have a Alolan Marowak with the ability Lighting Rod. But what I really want is his ability to be Rock Head. I farmed and tried to give him an ability capsule, but the ability capsule said that it was going to turn him into a Cursed Body Marowak.

If I change him into an Cursed Body Marowak and give him a ability capsule again, will it turn him into a Rock Head Marowak, or will it just switch him back into a Lighting Rod Marowak? Rock Head is not a hidden ability.

Answer (score 1):

> If I change him into an Cursed Body Marowak and give him a ability capsule again, will it turn him into a Rock Head Marowak, or will it just switch him back into a Lighting Rod Marowak?

**It will just switch it back to Lighting Rod**

As you can see here, [Marowak](https://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/105.shtml), it's hidden ability is Rock Head, and Hidden Abilities don't change with ability capsule.

Let me explain real quick.
Each pokemon has 3 ability slots, in Marowak and it's preevolution case, they have 3 different (Pokemon with just 1 ability used the first 2 slot for the same ability).

Cubone has the next abilities:

1. Rock Head.
2. Lightningrod
3. Hidden Ability: Battle Armor

And A-Marowak has the next ones:

1. Cursed Body
2. Lightningrod
3. Hidden Ability: Rock Head

And abilities change based on their ability slot, for example, if you get a Rock Head Cubone, it will become a Cursed Body A-Marowak, so, if you want a Rock Head A-Marowak, you need to breed or SOS Chain a Battle Armor Cubone.

Comment: Oh, Im an idiot. I Saw Cuebone have Rock Head as an ability and though Marowak would have it as an ability too... well then, is it possible to breed a Cuebone to get one with a hidden ability? And a side question, does egg hatching get slower if all your bag is filled with eggs? Because Im probably gonna have to have my party full of Cuebone eggs to find a hidden ability one, if I can.

Comment: You actually need one with the HA (hidden ability), you can't breed them (only if one of the parent has the HA you are actually going to be able to get one breeded, otherwise you won't). And no, it doesn't gets slower, is the same, try using a Magma Armor or Flame Body Pokemon to half the amount of steps needed to hatch.

Comment: ....so I need a Rock Head Marowak when that's what I need. Great, RIP me. Thanks for you help tho.

Comment: Actually a Battle Armor Cubone... since there is no wild A-Marowak. There are several guides on YouTube how to SOS Chain for Hidden abilities, here is a link to quick tips for Cubone, good luck! (https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/296576/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-these-pokemon-have-their-ha).